# Softmax Cross Entropy with Weights over Samples in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, reinforcement-learning, loss-function

Recently I got stuck in a policy-gradient problem. I was asked to implement an algorithm in which the loss function is defined as follows:

```
loss = \sum_i R_i(y_i\log h(x_i) + (1-y_i)\log (1-h(x_i)))
```

(as usual, here *{(x_i, y_i)} = {(input, label)}* in a classic *classification* problem, with function *h*, in my case, can be interpreted as a *neural network*)

This seems quite familiar with the normal *cross-entropy* *loss function*, except each term is multiplied with a weight R_i. And that's where problem came as I couldn't find any built-in *tensorflow* loss function which allowed me to assign weight to each sample. The instructions told me to use

```
tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits, labels)
```

which I found not-applicable in my case. Do you guys have any idea? Thank you in advance!

For more details, the task was to implement a Deep Reinforcement Learning algorithm, and here *x_i = state/observation, y_i = action,* and *h* a Neural Network to be trained to approximate policy function

Comment: See [tf.nn.weighted_cross_entropy_with_logits](http://devdocs.io/tensorflow~python/tf/nn/weighted_cross_entropy_with_logits)

Comment: [`tf.losses.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/losses/sparse_softmax_cross_entropy) has a `weights` argument that you can use to input a sample weight.